# using Thread multiple times for updating UI

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I write some timer. and I want to display it in `textview` after start button is clicked. 
What I did.
Every time I

```
timer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (!stopedButton ) {

                    time = "";
                    if (timerMinutes >= 60) {
                        timerMinutes = 0;
                        timerHours++;
                    }

                    if (timerHours < 10)
                        time = "0" + String.valueOf(timerHours) + ":";
                    else
                        time = String.valueOf(timerHours) + ":";
                    if (timerMinutes < 10)
                        time += "0" + String.valueOf(timerMinutes);
                    else
                        time += String.valueOf(timerMinutes);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if (!stopedButton) {
                                mTimeFromStartValue.setText(time);
                                timerMinutes++;
                            } else {
                                timerMinutes = 0;
                                timerHours = 0;
                            }
                        }

                    });
                    Log.e(TAG, ""+timerHours);
                    Log.e(TAG, ""+timerMinutes);
                    Log.e(TAG, time);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

so it works fine, but every time after stop and then start and after doing it many times my timer starts working fast. I try to avoid that kind of situation and I thought that i don't need to create new timer every time. But I need to have working timer after stop start too.

I wrote some code like this:

```
    if(timer.isAlive()){
        timer.resume();
    }else{
        timer.start();
    }
```

But I have got this exception: `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started`

so how to solve this ?

Comment: The recommended way for this sort of behaviour in android is TimerTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new `Thread` instance to start new thread. Also You need do use `interrupt()` method of `Thread` class.

Use this code to finish Your thread:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {

        // Your code here

        if(isInterrupted ()){
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Use this code when stop button was clicked:

```
timer.interrupt();
timer.join();
```